# running test using random values crashes sometimes with SIGABT. how to expose out of array bounds error in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run the following code for a heap but I'm getting this error randomly:

```
*** An abort error (SIGABRT) occurred during program execution.
*** This error is thrown by system functions that detect corrupt state.
***
```

and was wondering why for this code:

```
PQHeap::PQHeap() {
    _cap = 10;
    _elements = new int[_cap];
    _count = 0;
}

PQHeap::~PQHeap() {
    delete [] _elements;
}

void PQHeap::enqueue(int elem) {
    if (_count == _cap) {
        _cap *= 2;
        int * newHeap = new int[_cap];
        for (int i = 1; i <= _count; i += 1) {
            newHeap[i] = _elements[i];
        }
        delete [] _elements;
        _elements = newHeap;
    }
    _count += 1;
    int i = _count;
    _elements[i] = elem;
    if (i > _count) {
        error("out of bounds on line 33 i: " + integerToString(i));
        cout << "out of bounds on line 33 i: " + integerToString(i) << endl;
    } else {
    if (i == 1) {
        return;
    }
    int curr = elem;
    int parentI = i / 2;
    int parent = _elements[parentI];
    while (i > 1 && parent > curr) {
        _elements[parentI] = curr;
        _elements[i] = parent;
        i /= 2;
        parentI /= 2;
        curr = _elements[i];
        parent = _elements[parentI];
    }
}
}

int PQHeap::size() const {
    return _count;
}

void PQHeap::clear() {
    if (_count > 0) {
        delete [] _elements;
    }
    _cap = 10;
    _elements = new int[_cap];
    _count = 0;
}

int PQHeap::peek() const {
    if (_count > 0) {
        return _elements[1];
    }
    error("can't peek empty heap");
}

int PQHeap::dequeue() {
    if (_count == 0) {
        error("can't dequeue empty queue");
    } else {
    int dequeued = _elements[1];
    int i = 1;
    if (i < 1 || i > _count) {
        cout << "i is out of bounds, i: " << i << ", count: " << _count << endl;
    }
    int curr = _elements[_count];
    _elements[i] = curr;
    int child1I = 2 * i;
    int child1 = _elements[child1I];
    _count -= 1;
    int smallerChildI = child1I;
    int child2I = 2 * i + 1;
    if (child2I <= _count) {
        if (_elements[child2I] < child1) {
            smallerChildI = child2I;
        }
    }
    int smallerChild = _elements[smallerChildI];
    while(child1I <= _count && curr > smallerChild) {
        _elements[i] = _elements[smallerChildI];
        _elements[smallerChildI] = curr;
        i = smallerChildI;
        curr = _elements[i];
        child1I = 2 * i;
        child1 = _elements[child1I];
        smallerChildI = child1I;
        child2I = 2 * i + 1;
        if (child2I <= _count) {
            if (_elements[child2I] < child1) {
                smallerChildI = child2I;
            }
        }
        smallerChild = _elements[smallerChildI];
    }
    return dequeued;
}
    }

bool PQHeap::isEmpty() const {
    return _count == 0;
}
```

I was wondering how I might be able to get better information on this.  I tried to play around with removing the delete array statements to no avail.  I thought it might even be an out of bounds issue.  I'm not sure though with the undetailed error message I got.  I also tried to translate this into Java in hopes of using its error checking but I only would periodically get an out of bounds error, though not sure where.  Thank you.

Edit: I just confirmed that it was an out of bounds error as the Java code clarified. I was wondering how I might be able to expose this issue in c++ now without manually/procedurally adding it.

Comment: Do you have your compiler warnings enabled?  If so, is your code compiling without triggering any warnings? The code provided does not compile, hence does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes. I'm running it using qt creator and the one warning I get is only about my font.

Comment: After your edit: Does your question ask how to fix your out of bounds issue, or how you'd find out of bounds errors in your c++ program without translating it to java?

Comment: the latter.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= _count; i += 1) {
```

That looks off. Array indices are 0-based, so `[0..count-1]` not `[1..count]`. Fixed:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _count; ++i) {
        newHeap[i] = _elements[i];
    }
```

Likewise, the explicit bounds check is wrong:

```
    if (i < 1 || i > _count) {
        cout << "i is out of bounds, i: " << i << ", count: " << _count
             << endl;
    }
```

Should be

```
    size_t i = 1;
    if (i < 0 || i >= _count) {
```

There are some redundant/tautological checks:

```
size_t i = _count;
_elements[i] = elem;
if (i > _count) {
```

Can never be true. Likewise, if you used unsigned types (`size_t`) properly for indices, checks for <0 are redundant.

> Note, your code is not exception safe, and should be using standard algorithms, but I guess this is for a class and you are not allowed to use them.

The way to find out is by using checkers:

- Compile with warnings! (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on GCC/Clang, at a minimum)
- Use ASan/UBSan (GCC and Clang)
- Use Valgrind

### Demo: ASAN/UBSan

Compiled with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`, doing a simple test:

```
int main() {
    PQHeap heap;
    for (auto i : { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,
                    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }) {
        heap.enqueue(i);
    }
}
```

Already fails:

[image]

Line 42:

```
_elements[i] = elem;
```

So, `i` is out of bounds there. Turns out the condition earlier:

```
if (_count == _cap) {
```

should be

```
if (_count + 1 >= _cap) {
```

### Using Valgrind

Running instead of `./sotest` with `valgrind ./sotest`:

```
==29286== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29286== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29286== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29286== Command: ./sotest
==29286==
==29286== Invalid write of size 4
==29286==    at 0x1090C0: PQHeap::enqueue(int) (test.cpp:42)
==29286==    by 0x108D97: main (test.cpp:132)
==29286==  Address 0x61f2ca8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 40 alloc'd
==29286==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29286==    by 0x10902C: PQHeap::PQHeap() (test.cpp:24)
==29286==    by 0x108D8D: main (test.cpp:129)
==29286==
==29286== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29286==    at 0x1090E4: PQHeap::enqueue(int) (test.cpp:54)
==29286==    by 0x108D97: main (test.cpp:132)
==29286==
==29286==
==29286== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29286==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29286==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 72,824 bytes allocated
==29286==
==29286== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29286==
==29286== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29286== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==29286== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Points at the same line. Fixing it, and adding a dequeue loop:

```
while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
    std::cout << heap.dequeue() << " ";
}
```

Prints a whole array of errors:

```
==1306== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1306== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1306== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1306== Command: ./sotest
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x10916A: PQHeap::enqueue(int) (test.cpp:54)
==1306==    by 0x108DE7: main (test.cpp:132)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x10932F: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:120)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x1092F9: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:106)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x109307: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:107)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x10931E: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:115)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x1092FE: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:106)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x10930E: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:107)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x515F7AB: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x516DC55: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x108E11: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x515F4F3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x515F7D5: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x516DC55: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x108E11: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x515F505: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x515F7D5: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x516DC55: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x108E11: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1306==    at 0x515F80A: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x516DC55: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1306==    by 0x108E11: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x109320: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:117)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x109324: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:117)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
==1306== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1306==    at 0x1092F2: PQHeap::dequeue() (test.cpp:105)
==1306==    by 0x108E07: main (test.cpp:136)
==1306==
1 2 0 3 4 0 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 i is out of bounds, i: 1, count: 1
20 ==1306==
==1306== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1306==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1306==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 74,008 bytes allocated
==1306==
==1306== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1306==
==1306== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1306== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1306== ERROR SUMMARY: 56 errors from 14 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Just take them, 1 at a time.

```
while (i > 1 && parent > curr) {
```

depends on unitialized data. Which means that `_elements[parentI]` must be a location never written to (`parentI` is out of bounds?). Nah, `parentI` can't be out of bounds. In fact, it is likely 0. Which means, that we're off-by-one again. And indeed:

```
_count += 1;
size_t i = _count;
_elements[i] = elem;
```

Writes the first element to index 1, not 0. You'll get the rest, no doubt :/

### Many Fixes:

This will still have errors, but you might want to see what caught my eye: